# MS ACCESS SQL How to select all column header and list them as a column

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

Hi Guys i have a table call registrants which is like that

```
Registrants
Name    id    school    class    entrydate
yoyo     1    np          3      31/9/2013
```

However i want it to show like this instead

```
Registrants
Columns
Name
id
school
class
entrydate
```

Please help me as i wanted to populate them into a combobox. THank you Very Much

Comment: So, you want the combo-box to list all of the information for a registrant on one line for each registrant?  Do you want everything to show up only in the drop down list, or do you want it all to show up in the combo box field after the registrant is selected?

Comment: Just listing haha not a real combo box more like drop down list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a vba function

```
Public Function ColumnNames(tableName As String) As Variant
    Dim retVal() As String
    Dim table As Variant
    For Each table In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If table.Name = tableName Then
            Dim i As Integer
            ReDim retVal(table.Fields.Count - 1)
            For i = 0 To table.Fields.Count - 1
                retVal(i) = table.Fields(i).Name
            Next
        End If
    Next
    ColumnNames = retVal
End Function
```